# How to initialize and control web form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, webforms, textarea

I have a simple web form with 2 elements:

```
<form>
    <input id="number" name="number" maxlength="1" type="text" />
    <textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want to do the following through jQuery:

- I want to initialize #number with a zero (0) in gray #999
- I want to initialize #description with "Enter your reason here" in gray #999
- I want to control the #number by limiting input to 1-5 and changing the color to blue #00c when the person enters a number
- I want the gray numeral zero to disappear on element focus so the only thing that can be entered is a single digit from 1 to 5
- If the person moves focus away from #number and does not enter a 1 through 5, I want to put the gray numeral zero back in #number
- Once the single digit is entered, I want control or focus to move to #description and the gray initialized phrase in #description to disappear
- Finally, I want whatever is entered in #description to be done so in blue #00c

Thank you for taking time to help me with this.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called Watermarking. Try looking that up as there are tons of resources available. Also, the maximum length property of an input[type="text"] is maxlength, not maxsize.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have currently attempted?

Comment: @ChristianVarga: That link would be better is the author was brief and concise. Though I agree with statement, people posting questions that don't involve attempts aren't going to read something that in-depth and say "now I know what I did wrong, allow me to fix that".

Comment: @BradChristie If one person reads the article, my job is done :)

Answer (score 0):

you can control the font styles with css.  for eg:

```
input {color:#999;}
```

you can set the input values with jquery like this:

```
$('#number').val('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the watermark: [jquery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)

Regarding selective input: [jquery-validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

As far as the other tweaks:

```
$('#name').on('change',function(){ // re-empty field on invalid input
  if (this.value){
    var n = parseInt(this.value);
    if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 5)){
      $(this).val('').trigger('change');
    }
  }
}).on('keypress',function(){ // check for a valid number; continue to next field
  var n = parseInt(this.value,10);
  if (1 <= n && n <= 5){
    $('#description').focus();
  }
});
```

Between the above and the two plugins you can customize the colors or CSS classes as well.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in jsFiddle and I could not get it to work.